# Carry the row id of table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i am fetching followers list from instagram in an array that is stored in a session and then displaying the data in a tabular form

```
<table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th></th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Profile Picture</th>
            <th>Add</th>                                    
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <?

        $followers=$_SESSION["followers"];
        foreach ($followers['data'] as $data) 
            {?>
                <tbody> 
                    <tr> 

                        <td></td>
                        <td><? echo $data['username']; ?></td>  
                        <td><? echo $data['full_name']; ?></td> 

                        <td><a target = '_blank' href="<? echo $data['profile_picture']; ?>"><img name="image" src="<? echo $data['profile_picture']; ?>" width="40" height="40" alt="word" /></a></td>

                        <td><a href="a_add_vendor.php"><input type='image' src='img/add.png' title='Add' style="height:20px; width:20px;"></a></td>
                    </tr> 
                </tbody> 
          <?}?>
</table>
```

i want that when the add button is clicked, the page should redirect to next page i.e a_add_vendor.php and also carry the values of that specific row to the next page. While dealing with database i could carry the id of that row something like this a_add_vendor.php?id=id, but here the data is not related to database so can anyone tell me how i can do so

Comment: maybe put the info on `$_SESSION`

Comment: @Santa's helper if  i am using sessin then it is just storing the last value of the table

Comment: @user3732711 well its up to your useage if you put the a line like this at in your loop:
`$_SESSION['instagram'][$data['id']] = $data;`

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is changing the href to

```
    <a href="a_add_vendor.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']?>&fullname=<?php echo $data['fullname']?> .... (or whatever which properties you want to pass on
```

then in the PHP file :

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: in this method all the details get displayed in the url, which i wish to avoid. can u plz suggest some other way? can't I carry the id  value of table?

Comment: You could do it with a Post form, this way you'll have to change your table to a form you can find some more info on how to do that [here](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-variables.html) with some CSS you can make it look like it's still a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one of the following approach :-

1) Use Ajax to submit the details to the other page to execute the friends making logic. It will be more secure as none of the information is visible on the URL.

2) Use query string to send the information to other page and encrypt the id and other params to make it secure.

3) Use JS to add cookies for a particular request and use PHP on the other page to get these cookies and again reset for next request.

Comment: can u plz tell me how i can use ajax to do so

Comment: You can use the $.ajax({}) method and send params to the PHP. Check this link for more description:- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

instead of anchor tag, use some other HTML element like button and add the ajax method on click of the button to initiate the AJAX.